# HtmlAgilityPack ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse a website's content on Windows Phone using the HtmlAgilityPack. My current code is:

```
HtmlWeb.LoadAsync(url, DownloadCompleted);
...
void DownloadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = e.Document;
            if (doc != null)
            {
                string test = doc.DocumentNode.Element("html").Element("body").Element("form").Elements("div").ElementAt(2).Element("table").Element("tbody").Elements("tr").ElementAt(4).Element("td").Element("center").Element("div").InnerText.ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(test);
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently, when I run the above, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException at `string test = doc.DocumentNode.Element("html").Element("body").Element("form").Elements("div").ElementAt(2).Element("table").Element("tbody").Elements("tr").ElementAt(4).Element("td").Element("center").Element("div").InnerText.ToString();`.

`doc.DocumentNode.Element("html").InnerText.ToString()` seems to give me the source code for the entire page.

The URL of the website I'm trying to parse is: http://polyclinic.singhealth.com.sg/Webcams/QimgPage.aspx?Loc_Code=BDP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're after a specific `DIV`, if I'm not mistaking the one you're after has a unique identifier `<td class="queueNo"><center><div id="divRegPtwVal">0</div></center></td>`.

Why not simply use `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='divRegPtwVal']")` or `doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(div => div.Id == "divRegPtwVal").FirstOrDefault()`

---

Select the image source for a specific image with id:

```
 var attrib = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@id='imgCam2']/@src");
 //I suspect, might be a slightly different property, I can't check right now
 string src = attrib.InnerText;
```

Or:

```
var img = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").Where(img => img.Id=="imgCam2");
string src = img.Attributes["Source"].Value;
```

Comment: Yes! That did it! Thanks so much! One last question though, what if I want to get the `src` from <img id="imgCam2"> as well?

Comment: Oh, actually I'm getting null for the image's `InnerText`, and I can't get the second image code to work. Btw the SelectNode should be `SelectSingleNode`.

Comment: Ah, got it with:
`var test2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@id='imgCam2']");
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(test2.GetAttributeValue("src", ""));`